# CUDA C++, modifying a function so that it runs from device?

Tags: c++, cuda, device, host

I'm using CUDA C/C++, my CUDA compilation tools version is 7.0

I have a struct and a class:

```
struct racer{
    bool active;
    int Distance;
    int currentPosition;
};
```

The class:

```
class Game{
    public:
    vector <racer> racersVector;
    bool           runTimeStep();
}
```

And I have a class function that modifies "racersVector":

```
bool Game::runTimeStep(){

    //this is 1 timestep, this is the part of code to be run on the GPU with "racersVector.size()" blocks/threads in parallel
    //-----------------------
    for (int j = 0; j < racersVector.size(); j++){
        racersVector[j].currentPosition++;

        if (racersVector[j].currentPosition >= racersVector[j].Distance)
            racersVector[j].active = false;
    }
    //-----------------------

}
```

So, from my Main, I use the class in this way:

```
Game game1;
game1.initialise();

while(true){
    game1.runTimeStep();
}
```

I'm trying to use CUDA for the part of code that is commented, the idea is to copy the class object or the "vector  racersVector" instance to the device, run "computeTimeStep" (a CUDA kernel that I want to implement) as many times as I want and then, when I want to see the state of my vector, copy back the vector from the device to the host, so the ideal would be something like this:

```
Game game1;
game1.initialise();

here-the-code-to-copy-game1.racersVector-to-device

computeTimeStep <<<N,1>>> ();
computeTimeStep <<<N,1>>> ();
computeTimeStep <<<N,1>>> ();
computeTimeStep <<<N,1>>> ();
computeTimeStep <<<N,1>>> ();
copyBackToHost (game1.racersVector);
game1.printInfo();
```

So I modified my main program:

```
int main() 
{
    Game game1;
    game1.initialise();

    //trying to copy game1.racersVector to device
    vector<racer> *d_vec;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_vec, sizeof(game1.racersVector));
    cudaMemcpy(d_vec, &game1.racersVector, sizeof(game1.racersVector), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

If I understood it correctly, this should have copied "game1.racersVector" to the device

The idea is to create a CUDA function (kernel) that does 1 timestep with the "vector  racersVector", But when I try create a CUDA kernel that takes a vector pointer as a parameter:

```
__global__ void computeTimeStep (vector<racer> *cud){

    cud->resize(4);
}
```

nvcc says:

```
cudaex2.cu(46): error: calling a __host__ function("std::vector<racer, std::allocator<racer> > ::resize") from a __global__ function("computeStep") is not allowed
```

How can I copy "racersVector" to the device and then work with that vector  using a CUDA kernel?

Comment: The really short answer is that you can't. There is no C++ standard library support on the GPU - there is no `std::vector` support in device code,

Comment: I saw that "thrust::device_vector<int> something" and "thrust::host_vector<int> something" are available in CUDA; or I'm in the wrong track?

Comment: Again, those are intended for use in host code, they can't be directly used in device code.

Comment: ok, thanks @talonmies, I'm a beginner, so I'd also appreciate some suggestions too, is there a way (any way) to run a timestep (the part of code enclosed by comments) using CUDA to take advantage of parallel processing? (so to run that with racersVector.size() blocks in parallel)

Comment: Sure, it's possible.  Drop the usage of `std::vector` and use some other data storage method, such as an ordinary C array.  As written, @talonmies has already given you the correct answer to your question.  You cannot use `std::vector` in device code, especially if what you want is `resize()`.  Use an array of `racer` instead.